# MonoDroid - How to get the custom attribute value of a widget defined in the layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget, xamarin.android

I am trying to get the value of a custom attribute of a custom widget programmatically.

The widget extends the LinearLayout, I have defined the custom attributes as follows:

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomWidget">
    <attr name="customProperty" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And are current attempting to access the value of 'customProperty' like so:

```
public CustomWidget(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
    : base(context, attrs)
{
    var a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.CustomWidget);
    var s = a.GetString(Resource.Styleable.CustomWidget_customProperty);
}
```

I have also tried calling this code in the OnFinishInflate() method as-well and no luck.

Its probably worth mentioning that this widget is located in a separate android library project to the one that it is being used in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this working just fine in [MonoDroid.ActionBar](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MonoDroid.ActionBar). So where you might fall into a pit is when trying to use the Custom Attributes. You have to remember to declare a xmlns namespace in your XML and refer it to the correct namespace of your application.

So lets say your namespace is `My.Awesome.App` where you contain your `CustomWidget` somewhere, then your `axml` layout could look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.awesome.app"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <my.awesome.app.CustomWidget
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        cs:customProperty="Awesome!"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

So notice that a `cs` xmlns namespace has been declared, and this is used in your `CustomWidget` declaration in the `axml` to pass the string `Awesome!` to your custom layout.

Now you should be able to get the `customProperty` in the constructor of your `CustomWidget`:

```
//Custom Attributes (defined in Attrs.xml)
var a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.CustomWidget);

var awesomeProperty = a.GetString(Resource.Styleable.CustomWidget_customProperty);
if (null != awesomeProperty)
    //do something with it...

//Don't forget to recycle it
a.Recycle();
```

Comment: Don't forget that namespaces in Android are lowercase. So your own should be written in lowercase in `AXML` files.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Looks like `Resource.Styleable` no longer exists. Do you know how to accomplish the above now?

Comment: It is there. It is generated on build, just like all other values in Resources. Check your Resources.Designer.cs file.